# SQL Snowflake - Put an SQL list / array into a column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Based on a specific project architecture, I have a LIST `('Bob', 'Alice')` that I want to SELECT as a column (and do a specific JOIN afterwards).

Right now, I did :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(flatten(input => ('Bob', 'Alice'))) as v1
```

But this resulted in one row / two columns, and I need one column / two rows (to do the JOIN).

Same if I use :

```
select * from (values ('Bob', 'Alice'))
```

The basic idea would be to PIVOT, however, the list may be of arbitrary length so I can't manually list all column names in PIVOT query...

Also I can't use the following (which would work) :

```
select * from (values ('Bob'), ('Alice'))
```

because I inherit the list as a string and can't modify it on the fly.

Comment: Have you looked at SPLIT_TO_TABLE, would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed set of values that you are wanting to JOIN against, and looking at some of the SQL you have tried the correct form to use VALUES is:

```
select * from (values ('Bob'), ('Alice'));
```

or

```
select * from values ('Bob'), ('Alice');
```

if you have a exist array you can FLATTEN it like for first example

```
SELECT v1.value::text
FROM TABLE(flatten(input => array_construct('Bob', 'Alice'))) as v1;
```

| V1.VALUE::TEXT |
| --- |
| Bob |
| Alice |

or if you have a string "Bob, Alice" then [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html)

```
SELECT trim(v1.value)
FROM TABLE(split_to_table('Bob, Alice', ',')) as v1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is provided as `('Bob','Alice')` then [STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_split_to_table.html) could be used:

```
SELECT table1.value 
FROM table(strtok_split_to_table($$('Bob','Alice')$$, '(),''')) AS table1;
```

Output:

[image]